# Multiple definition error in c++, can fix?

Tags: c++

So I have this assignment code I need to do -

student_header.h -

```
#include <string>
struct student{
    std::string name;
    int roll_no;
    float cgpa;
};

class students{
    student students_list[15];
    public:
        void enroll(int);
};
```

student_functions.cpp -

```
#include <iostream>
#include "student_header.h"
using namespace std;
void students :: enroll(int c){
    cout<<"Enter name : ";
    cin>>students_list[c].name;
    cout<<"Enter roll number : ";
    cin>>students_list[c].roll_no;
    cout<<"Enter CGPA : ";
    cin>>students_list[c].cgpa;
}
```

main.cpp -

```
#include "student_functions.cpp"

int main() {
    students students1;
    students1.enroll(0);
    return 0;
}
```

And it gives me this error -

```
/tmp/ccho8KVZ.o: In function `students::enroll(int)':
student_functions.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `students::enroll(int)'
/tmp/ccf99dv4.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
```

It gives this error for all functions that I have declared and am using. You can see I have not defined the functions anywhere else but once in that file.
Can anyone fix this?

Comment: As a practice, don't include .cpp files in other .cpp files. Include just the .h file.

Comment: @cigien but how will my main file use the functions? my assignment requires me to have 3 files. I'm sorry if this sounds stupid but I am new to c++

Comment: Your header file is lacking header guards. That will bite you eventually.

Answer (score 3):

You should include *header files*, not *source files*.

Instead of

```
#include "student_functions.cpp"
```

You should use

```
#include "student_functions.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

As others said, you need to include the header file `student_functions.h` and not the .cpp file.
Why?

because `student_functions.cpp` is compiled (your IDE does it automatically because it is a .cpp file.). and your main file is compiled.
Since you include the cpp file, you now have two definitions of `enroll(int)`:
one in your main file (via include of `student_functions.cpp`)
one in your `student_functions.cpp`.

As a rule of thumb, do not include definitions, include declarations (templates are an exception most of the time).